# JSON Workflow Designer and Engine

Tags: json, workflow, workflow-foundation

I am having problems trying to get WF4 to call JSON services.  I wanted to know if anyone has used any other types of JSON based workflow engines that are either free or open source, and have a good designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do? Do you want an activity to call a specific service that returns a json object? If so, than you just need to create a custom activity which calls this service with http client  for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Workflow Engine](https://workflowengine.io/). Though the engine itself uses XML, I'm sure it won't be a bother implementing a converter. And it does have a visual HTML5-based designer.